# Hive Java API register jars

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I am using **Cloudera 5.3.1** and using corresponding **Hive API** I am able to make some queries through Java. However some of my queries need some UDFs for which I add jars.

I have added jars from .hiverc, which is well taken by hive commandline. However Java it is not taking jars when calling from Java API. I have added jars in the following class path but no use :-

```
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hive/lib/
```

Looks like hive is not taking the above as classpath. For now I am executing Hiveql query to add jars individually for each statement:-

```
stmt.execute("add jar hdfs:///user/hive/aux_jars/opencsv.jar");
```

After above I execute other statements I want. But there must a way for hive to take jars automatically when taking commands from Java API. Could somebody suggest what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to set the Hive Auxiliary JARs Directory property via Cloudera Manager and then you register the jar as function within Hive.

Detailed information can be found in the [Cloudera documentation](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/cm_mc_hive_udf.html).